# WebSocketを使ったウェブアプリでの接続エラー

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, go, websocket

プログラミング初心者です。
現在Go言語を学習しており、「Go言語によるWebアプリケーション開発」という書籍を使っているのですが、その中のWebSocketを使ったチャットアプリ作成にて、下記のエラーが出て解決できずにいます。

`room:36 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/room' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

書籍で使われている、GitHubにあがっているコードを使い、接続先のみ変更して試しましたが、同様のエラーとなりました。
下記にコードを載せます。何が問題なのか、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>チャット</title>
    <style>
      input { display:block; }
      ul { list-style: none; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <h2>Websocketを使ったアプリケーション</h2>
    <form id="chatbox">
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="送信">
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        var socket = null;
        var msgBox = $("#chatbox textarea");
        var messages = $("#messages");
        $("chatbox").submit(function(){
          if(!msgBox.val()) return false;
          if(!socket){
            alert("エラー：WebSocket接続が行われていません。");
            return false;
          }
          socket.send(msgBox.val());
          msgBox.val("");
          return false;
        });

        if (!window["WebSocket"]){
          alert("エラー：Websocketに対応していないブラウザです。");
        } else {
          socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/room");
          socket.onclose = function(){
            alert("接続が終了しました。");
          }
          socket.onmessage = function(e){
            messages.append($("<li>").text(e.data));
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ” Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200”(WebSocketでコネクションができるまでのやり取り手順(ハンドシェーク)におけるエラー：200(OK)という返されるはずのない応答がサーバから来た）というのがエラーメッセージの内容です。このメッセージだけではサーバ側、クライアント側のどちらに原因があるか判断はできませんので、サーバ側のプログラムにも疑いの目を向けるべきかと思います。

Comment: 遅くなってすみません。
解決はできていませんが、アドバイス頂きありがとうございました。